# Why lost communication to Touchpad on Wayland Debian Stretch after FN-8/9 keys?

Tags: debian, drivers, touchpad, wayland, focaltech

I had second display connected to my laptop before, Google Chrome wants to stay there often. 
I tried to restore the second display without having the second monitor connected to the laptop (because I wanted to use Google Chrome, Quit does not help). 
I pressed FN-F9 and then FN-F8 after which I lost the communication to touchpad. Keyboard works fine.
I restarted the system many times but still the problem occurs. 
I do not understand why.

I tried to restore the problem by pressing again the FN keys but no resolution. 
I want to restore the working touchpad on Wayland Debian.

Lost communication on the touchpad in Wayland now. 
No touch works. No pressing of the touchpad works.

I can log back to X11 where the touchpad works.

### Testing Joshua's proposals

1. Do `gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub`, edit `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet i8042.nomux=1 i8042.reset"`, `sudo update-grub` successfully and reboot but output still failure with touchpad.
2. Do `gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub`, edit  `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i8042.nomux=1 i8042.reset"`, `sudo update-grub` successfully and reboot but output still failure with touchpad.

OS: Debian Stretch 9.1
Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UA R4028T
Touchpad: FocalTechPS
Window manager: Gnome 3.22 on Wayland 1.12

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue similar to that and was able to [find a solution](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Libinput#Troubleshooting) on the Arch Wiki. It seems like 4.1 and 4.3 would be good, easy things to try. For me, it was actually adding these kernel options:

```
i8042.nomux=1 i8042.reset
```

Comment: You can do that; whatever you're comfortable with. You'd add the parameters to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` then run `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: If that's a copy/paste from your grub config, it may fail with 'queiet' (it should be 'quiet').

Comment: `update-grub` fails or the touchpad still doesn't work after reboot?

Comment: I think I have a Zenbook in the office. I'll get Debian up and running and see if I can recreate the issue tomorrow.

Comment: I haven't been able to recreate the problem you're having yet, no. I've tried, but the behavior simply isn't happening on my end.

Comment: I expanded studying the logs about the issue here https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/400153/16920