# How to find logs about Touchpad malfunction in Debian on Wayland?

Tags: debian, logs, touchpad, troubleshooting, wayland

I am trying to troubleshoot why my touchpad does not work anymore with Debian on Wayland (after pressing FN9 and FN8), continuing from the thread [Why lost communication to Touchpad on Wayland Debian Stretch after FN-8/9 keys?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/397898/why-lost-communication-to-touchpad-on-wayland-debian-stretch-after-fn-8-9-keys)

Restarting the system does not restore the touchpad. 
So some touchpad setting files have been affected. 
I really would like to troubleshoot which those files are such that the touchpad could work again.

The touchpad works normally in X11, but not anymore in Wayland.

- `evtest`: produces events in X11 - very fast from the beginning.
- `evtest`: it took one minute before it managed to produce any events.

OS: Debian Stretch 9.1
Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UA R4028T
Touchpad: FocalTechPS
Window manager: Gnome 3.22 on Wayland 1.12

Comment: Run `evtest` (as root), select touchpad and verify the kernel input layer is still producing events. For Wayland, `libinput` handles input devices, so that's where to look next (but I'm not very familiar with it).

Comment: @dirkt How to look with `libinput` the case? - - `evtest` produces events both in X11 and Wayland but significantly faster in X11.

Comment: That's strange, because the kernel layer is the same, no matter if X11 or Wayland runs on top. So `evtest` should produce events in exactly the same way, at the same speed. Do you run anything else that "grabs" (monopolizes) the input interface? Any timeouts anywhere in any logs? Any differences in `dmesg`?

Comment: @dirkt Can you propose any specific `dmesg` commands to test it?

Comment: have you looked into `libinput` tools like `libinput-debug-events` and similar?  on Stretch you may need the `libinput-tools` package.  see also https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/